# Google Places Autocomplete API Over Limit Solutions

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, geocoding

I have this error: "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API."

Currently, the form is set up to force select the first match from the API. 
I would like to not force select the first match when exceeding this daily limit. I thought the status= "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" would work, but turns out this is the status I get = "ZERO_RESULTS".

Anyone have any idea why "ZERO_RESULTS" come back instead of "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"?

Here is a piece of my code:

```
geocoder.geocode({"address": firstResult}, function (results, status) {

                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                            var formattedResult = results[0].formatted_address;
                            $("#input-location").val(formattedResult);
                        }
                    }
                    if (status == "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT") {
                        $(".btn-search-submit").removeAttr('disabled');
                        return;
                    }
                    if (status == 'ZERO_RESULTS') {
                        $(".search-no-results").remove();
                        $(".btn-search-submit").attr('disabled', true);
                        $(".pac-container").show();
                        $(".pac-container").append(
                                "<div class='search-no-results'>" +
                                "<p><strong> Sorry, no results</strong></p>" +
                                "<p>Please check your spelling or try a zipcode</p>" +
                                "</div>");

                        setTimeout(function(){
                            $(".pac-container").hide();
                        }, 3000);
                    }
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like more of a business/software engineering question than a programming question.

You can see the cost of Google Maps API requests here: https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/usage-limits#limitexceeded

And you can see the pricing plans available here: https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/#details

If you're going over the limit, it might be time to just upgrade the pricing plan.

Comment: Thanks Rudolf for your response. I am checking in for an upgrade - but just to be safe I would like to know how I can catch this error and switch the behavior of my form so it doesn't "force" select the first option. Would you know why I cannot grab the "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" status? The status code comes back as "ZERO_RESULTS"

Comment: haven't seen that locally; but someone has an answer over on the GIS StackExchange: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/15365